# What is the necessary condition for two integrals of a product of two functions with one common function to be equal

Tags: calculus

Consider three continuous, differentiable and integrable functions $f(x), g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and the following two integrals:

$$I := \int_0^\infty f(x)h(x)\,\mathrm dx,\quad\text{and}\quad J := \int_0^\infty g(x)h(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ with $I$ and $J$ convergent.

The question is: does $I = J$ requires that $f(x) = g(x)$ ? 
Or equivalently: if $f(x)$ is not equal to $g(x)$, then $I$ is not equal to $J$?

A quick reasoning by contradiction implies that if I = J, then it is necessary that f(x) = g(x) and the converse is true. However, I believe there must be a more rigorous proof.

Comment: Take $h\equiv 0$ and $f,g$ any functions.

Comment: the limits of integration are the same in both integrals? Or they are indefinite integrals?

Comment: I assume you mean for non-zero $h$, correct?

Comment: Correct, non zero f. g and h, definite integrals from zero to infinity

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not the case, with the simplest example being $h =0$.
It is also false for non-zero $h$.

*However*, if you assume that the equality $I=J$ holds for all $h$, then you result becomes true.
So it is a big difference if your equation is supposed to hold for a specific $h$ or all $h$.

*proof for the case $\forall h$*:

Assume $I=J$ for all $h$. We choose $h=f-g$.
Then we have
$$
 0=I-J = \int (f-g)h \mathrm dx = \int (f-g)^2 \mathrm dx.
$$
But the right-hand side can only be zero if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.
Thus $f=g$ follows.

Edit: per request, an example for a nonzero $h$ would be the function
$$
  h(x) = (x-1)^2 \quad x \in [0,1] \\
  h(x) = 0 \phantom{-1)^2} \quad x \geq 1
$$
Then for any function $f\neq g$ with the property $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$
the result is $I=J=0$ despite $f\neq g$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for a given, not any h, not equal to zero, the result (f =g) is not true? would you show why?

Comment: correct. I edited to give a counterexample for nonzero $h$.

Comment: What if f and g are > 0 and h < 0, not null?

Comment: then it is also wrong. is one counterexample not enough?

Comment: n the counter example h(x) = 0 for x >= 1. My question concerns the case where h(x) is not equal to zero.

Comment: ok, then it is possible to find another counterexample for that case, but it is harder to find.

Comment: The counter example uses h = 0. for x >= 1 My question is for when f > 0 ,    g > 0 , and h > 0, all not null.

Comment: yes, i understand. But there seems to be some context missing if you keep adding assumptions

Comment: The  context is to find the necessary conditions for f, g, h so that  I = J = 0. e.g. being not null,  and f and g one-to one

Comment: That sounds quite different to your original question. I suggest that you ask that question in a new post